# Click-to-zoom on a div created with ng-repeat

Tags: css, angularjs, animation, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm currently building an Angular/Firebase app that allows a teacher to push a question out to multiple students, and then collect the students' answers on a single screen to be projected.  (I don't have a live version up, but the files are [here](https://github.com/ThirdFoundation/ng-scratchpost/tree/refactor) on Github).  Each student gets a little div in which their answer is recorded, and the divs automatically organize and resize themselves.  The actual data is in a participants object in Firebase, bound to the model as $scope.participants:

```
participants: {
  Joe:  { response: "Joe's answer"  },
  Sam:  { response: "Sam's answer"  },
  Fred: { response: "Fred's answer" }
}
```

... and the display section is a container div populated by the ng-repeat, with a button that will call a function to add (or remove) a "zoomed" class to the specific div whose button was clicked:

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, val) in participants" ng-class="{zoomed: zoomIndex==={{$index}} }">
  <span>{{key}}</span>
  <span>{{val.response}}</span>
  <button ng-click="zoom($index)">Click to zoom</button>
</div>

zoom = function(val) {
  if ($scope.zoomIndex !== val) {
    $scope.zoomIndex = val;
  } else {
    $scope.zoomIndex = 999;
  }
}
```

**THE PROBLEM:**

I can't get any kind of sensible zoom animation.  The goal is to have the chosen div go from being one-among-many to filling the window.  I tried adding absolute positioning and kicking up the z-index, but there's an immediate skip as it pops out of the lineup and jumps to the upper left corner before slowly growing.  I tried leaving it in place and just having it swell to shove the others out of the way, but there's a skip there, too, if it's not the first in its row ... it grows and pushes everything else off its line, and then when it's too large to fit in the remaining space, it skips down to the line below.

```
zoomed {
  height: 97%;
  width: 97%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}
```

I thought about having it slide to the left as it grows, but I couldn't figure out how to get it to swap spots with other divs, and I thought about leaving it alone and creating a copy that's absolutely positioned right on top of it, that would then zoom, but I couldn't wrap my brain around it.  If possible, I'd like to accomplish this with just Angular and CSS.

Any thoughts are welcome, including "Your whole methodology is wrong; restructure things."  I've only got about six months of self-taught coding experience, so I'm almost certainly making mistakes.

Comment: Have you considered using angular bootstrap's accordion? Google it for a quick demo.  That way you could display a summary but when the teacher selects a students div, it expands fully.

Comment: @ThirdFoundation Is that right 'zoomed:' class or is it 'zoomed' class without the colon? Also, it seems that code you provided is not present to your project in github.

Answer (score 0):

There should not be : after the class name.
If you want to achieve the desired animation on hover then it should be

```
zoomed:hover {
  height: 97%;
  width: 97%;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
  transition: all 0.5s ease; 
}
```

so that once that element gets hovered then above animation will get applied

Comment: Thanks for catching the colon typo.  I'm not looking to achieve the animation on hover, but instead on a click.  However, the problem is with the animation itself ... the "skips" mentioned above.